# Backbone-route click doesn't not respond on 2nd attempt

Tags: backbone.js, validation

I am doing form validation in a function when a user wants to preview an invoice which is called by a route:

```
routes: {
        "new"                   : "newInvoice",
        "new/:assignmentid"     : "newInvoiceAssignment",
        "edit/:invoiceid"       : "editInvoice",
        "preview/:invoiceid"    : "previewInvoice",
        "preview"               : "preview",
        "delete/:invoiceid"     : "deleteInvoiceModal",
        "whyCant"               : "whyCant",
        "whatsThis"             : "whatsThis"
    },
```

And here is my two buttons (actually, a button and an href) on the form:

```
<div class="span8 alignRight">
    <button id="saveInvoiceDraft" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Save Draft</button>
    <a id="previewInvoice" class="btn btn-primary">Preview &amp; Send</a>
</div>
```

When this invoice is created, the URL for the  tag is set with:

```
var url = '#preview';
$('#previewInvoice').attr('href',url);
```

And finally, when I click on the "Preview & Send" button, the previewInvoice(invoiceid) function below runs, properly catches the one form field missing and displays the error message. At that point even if I populate the form field, that button is dead and no longer responds. However, the "Save Draft" button works perfectly and mimic's the same code as in the previewInvoice() function.

I know there is probably a better way to do this, but I was following that way it was done in another section of the app I inherited. Actually, as I am typeing this I am wondering since the sendDraft() function works and its a button and the previewInvoice() function does not, the fact that it is a href might have something to do with it.

```
function previewInvoice(invoiceid) {
    var invoice = new Invoice({"invoiceid": invoiceid});
    invoice.set({"invoiceid": invoiceid,"invoicestatus": "draft"});
    formGetter(invoice);
    validateInvoiceForm(invoice);

    if (window.errors.length == 0) {
        //business logic here

        if (window.panel == undefined) {
            // business logic here
        }
        else {
            //save business logic here
        }
    }
    else {
        showInvoiceErrors();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the button no longer responds? I am not seeing any error's in the console. I added a consol.log inside the function to display the value of a different form element, and it displays the first time in the console, but if I change the data and click the button again, that log does not update, which to me is another clue that it is just not firing.

Answer (score 1):

[`Backbone.History`](http://backbonejs.org/#History) listens to `hashchange` events to trigger navigation to routes. When you first click the `previewInvoice` button, the URL hash fragment is set to `#preview`, and the matching route is triggered.

When you click the same button the second time, the hash doesn't actually change, and therefore the router doesn't catch it.

I'm having a hard time recommending a good solution to this problem. Normally I would recommend catching the  click event and calling `router.navigate("preview", {trigger:true});` manually. However, based on your code sample it looks like your application is built around the `Router`, and there isn't a `View` layer for DOM event handling as you would expect in most Backbone applications.

On the Router level this is a bit trickier to solve. You could use `router.navigate` to set a dummy hash after the `preview` route has been executed. This would cause the link to trigger a `hashchange` on the second time as well. Unfortunately this would mean that the `preview` page would not be bookmarkable, and since you're not using pushState, would leave an extraneous history entry.

I'm afraid this issue will have to either be solved with a hacky fix (as outlined above) or a major refactoring.

Comment: Thanks. That helps me understand it a little more. What is weird is the other button on this page for Save Draft works the way I want it to and that's without a hash change. I'll try your suggestion and let you know how it goes. We are using views as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem, my solution is to put in a handler that does a fake "in-between" route that is hidden from history, so that Backbone.history will register the navigation as a change and trigger the action.

Put a class on links that you need the route action to trigger regardless if the URL is the same:

```
<a href="/someaction" class="js-ensureNav">do it</a>
```

In your Backbone view, put in an event handler:

```
events: {
    "click .js-ensureNav": "_ensureNav",
},
```

Actual handler:

```
_ensureNav: function (event) {
    var route_name = $(event.target).attr('href').slice(1);
    Backbone.history.navigate("fake");
    Backbone.history.navigate(route_name, {trigger: true, replace: true});
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of**

var url = '#preview';

$('#previewInvoice').attr('href',url);

**Try this**

var date = new Date();

var url = '#preview?date:' + date ;

$('#previewInvoice').attr('href',url);

So Every time new request will be generated and this will solve your problem.